# Serialize a method invocation to JSON then deserialize and call the method

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, system.reflection

I need to find a way to serialize a method call and it's associated parameter.  This is because we'll be passing payloads onto a queue (like MSMQ) and then later on a process will pick up the message and need to deserialize the payload and call the method required.

Both sides of the queue use the same C# library, but one is inside a Web context and the other is inside a batch process / console app.

I have demonstrated below what I'd like to do, however, I realise it may not be possible.  I know I could always encapsulate the meta data of what target method call and the have some huge switch statement that maps a parameter/payload to a method, however, it would be very cool and succinct if I could call any method I want (it doesn't matter whether it's static).

```
namespace SerializableMethodCalls
{
public class DTO
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public int AnInteger { get; set; }
}

public class DTO2
{
    public string MyData2 { get; set; }
    public int AnInteger2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static Queue<string> _queue = new Queue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DTO payload = new DTO
        {
            AnInteger = 45678,
            MyData = "Test"
        };

        DTO2 payload2 = new DTO2
        {
            AnInteger2 = 534653,
            MyData2 = "test2"
        };

        DoSomething(payload);
        DoSomething(payload2);



        _queue.Enqueue(Serialize(DoSomething, payload));

        while (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var message = _queue.Dequeue();
            DeserializeAndCallMethod(message);
        }

    }

    private static void DeserializeAndCallMethod(string message)
    {
        // somehow deserialize the method invocation and then call the method with the serialized payload!
    }

    public static void DoSomething(DTO2 payload2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done2! {0}, {1}", payload2.AnInteger2, payload2.MyData2);
    }

    public static void DoSomething(DTO dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done! {0}, {1}", dto.AnInteger, dto.MyData);
    }

    public static string Serialize(Method method, object parameter)
    {
        // somehow serialize a method call!?
    }
}
```

}

I'd be interested in hearing your thoughts

Many thanks

Kris

Comment: I'll list, what you need to serialize for a saved method call: AssemblyId・Classname・Methodname・ArgumentTypes (meaning AssemblyId・Classname for each) and finally your parameters values.

Comment: With support of generics and special methods, this becomes a bit more complex, though.

Answer (score 2):

Convert with the demonstrated `From/To...` methods between your DTOs and reflective objects:

```
class TypeDTO {
    public string AssemblyName;
    public string ClassName;

    public static TypeDTO FromType(Type type) {
        return new TypeDTO() {
            AssemblyName = type.Assembly.FullName,
            ClassName = type.FullName
        };
    }

    public Type ToType() {
        return ToType(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }

    public Type ToType(AppDomain domain) {
        Assembly assembly = domain.GetAssemblies().Where(t => t.FullName == AssemblyName).Single();
        return assembly.GetType(ClassName);
    }
}

class MethodSignatureDTO {
    public TypeDTO DeclaringType;
    public string MethodName;
    public TypeDTO[] ParameterTypes;

    public static MethodSignatureDTO FromMethod(MethodInfo method) {
        return new MethodSignatureDTO() {
            DeclaringType = TypeDTO.FromType(method.DeclaringType),
            MethodName = method.Name,
            ParameterTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(t => TypeDTO.FromType(t.ParameterType)).ToArray()
        };
    }
    public MethodInfo ToMethod() {
        return ToMethod(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }

    public MethodInfo ToMethod(AppDomain domain) {
        Type[] parameterTypes = ParameterTypes.Select(t => t.ToType(domain)).ToArray();
        return DeclaringType.ToType(domain).GetMethod(MethodName, parameterTypes);
    }
}

class MethodCallDTO {
    public MethodSignatureDTO Method;
    public object Instance;
    public object[] Arguments;

    public object Invoke() {
        return Invoke(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }

    public object Invoke(AppDomain domain) {
        return Method.ToMethod(domain).Invoke(Instance, Arguments);
    }
}
```